# Adding markers to a hashmap without adding them to the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add google map markers to this hashmap:

```
private HashMap<Marker, MyMarker> mMarkersHashMap;
```

without adding them to the google map. This is the code I currently have:

```
MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
mMarkersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);
```

This code adds the markers to the hashmap but also adds the markers to the map(using addMarker), which I don't want. Any suggestions

Here is the function I am working on:

```
private void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers)
    {
        if(markers.size() > 0)
        {
            for (final MyMarker myMarker : markers)
            {
                MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));

                Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
                //Passes markers into hashmap so they can be used by the information window methods
                mMarkersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);

                mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                        Intent ListIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoWindowList.class);
                        MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);
                        String title = myMarker.getmLabel();
                        ListIntent.putExtra("COUNTY", title);
                        startActivity(ListIntent);
                    }
                });

                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }

        }
        mClusterManager.addItems(markers);
    }
```

I want `mClusterManager.addItems(markers);` to add the markers to the map.

Here is my information window function which needs the hashmap to set information windows on the markers in the hashmap:

```
public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter
    {
        public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {

            View v  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
            MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);

            ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);
            TextView markerLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.marker_label);
            TextView anotherLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.another_label);
            //anotherLabel.setOnClickListener(newsfeed);

            markerIcon.setImageResource(manageMarkerIcon(myMarker.getmIcon()));
            anotherLabel.setText("Newsfeed");
            markerLabel.setText(myMarker.getmLabel());

            return v;

        }
    }
```

The MyMarker class:

```
public class MyMarker implements ClusterItem {
    private String mLabel;
    private String mIcon;
    private Double mLatitude;
    private Double mLongitude;
    private final LatLng mPosition;

    public MyMarker(String label, String icon, Double latitude, Double longitude)
    {
        this.mLabel = label;
        this.mLatitude = latitude;
        this.mLongitude = longitude;
        this.mIcon = icon;
        mPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }

    //mPosition = LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public String getmLabel()
    {
        return mLabel;
    }

    public void setmLabel(String mLabel)
    {
        this.mLabel = mLabel;
    }

    public String getmIcon()
    {
        return mIcon;
    }

    public void setmIcon(String icon)
    {
        this.mIcon = icon;
    }

    public Double getmLatitude()
    {
        return mLatitude;
    }

    public void setmLatitude(Double mLatitude)
    {
        this.mLatitude = mLatitude;
    }

    public Double getmLongitude()
    {
        return mLongitude;
    }

    public void setmLongitude(Double mLongitude)
    {
        this.mLongitude = mLongitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: just dont add markers to you map and only to hashmap , can you post more code of your class.

Comment: I know that is what I have to do, I am wondering how its done. Yeah i will add some more code now

Answer (score 1):

A "Marker" is created when you give `MarkerOptions` to the map and call `addMarker` so you cannot get a marker without first adding it to the map first.

if you are just trying to not have the marker visible then change its visibility

Comment: This gives me an error when I click on the map. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.cillin.map.MyMarker.getmIcon()' on a null object reference

Comment: Its for getting the icon(image) for the information window. I have added the code to the question.

Comment: where is your map click or whatever that calls that method

Comment: Inside the plotMarkers class

Comment: I dont see anywhere in `plotMarkers` where `getmIcon` is referenced

Comment: It's not there. You asked where is the onclick method called and the onInfoWindowClick is called in plotMarkers. getmIcon is initialized in the MyMarker class above.

Comment: you said you click on the map and it throws the error, so I asked where is the code that does that AND calls the getmIcon method. Please provide all the information inorder for me to answer correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105928/discussion-between-cian-and-tyczj).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the marker to the map, but then hide it using

```
currentMarker.setVisible(false);
```

Not sure that is the most efficient route, though.. Depends on your use-case.

---

*edit based on commments*

If maintaining a `HashMap` of markers is all you need to do, have you tried using a `ClusterRenderer`?

Here's an example:

```
clusterManager.setRenderer(new DefaultClusterRenderer<MyMarker>(activity, map, clusterManager) {
            @Override
            protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyMarker myMarker, Marker marker) {
                super.onClusterItemRendered(mobileMarker, marker);
                // add to hashmap here
            }

            ... override other methods as needed

        });

clusterManager.addItems(markers)
```

Comment: This gives me an error when I click on the map. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.cillin.map.MyMarker.getmIcon()' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you share the `MyMarker` class?

Comment: Yes. I added it to the end of my question.

Comment: I'm guessing whenever you lookup the marker from the `Map`, you're getting a null reference, hence the NPE. Sounds like something's off in your algorithm, but you at least want to check within `MarkerInfoWindowAdapter.getInfoContents` if `myMarker` is `null`

Comment: Also, why are you adding the markers to the map, and then adding them again to the `ClusterManager`? Wouldn't this this be creating the same map marker twice? That could be the source of your NPE

Comment: I want to use the ClusterManager to add the items, and then use the hashmap to set up the information windows. That's why I am asking how can I add the markers to the hashmap without adding them to the map.